# Get RibbonBarButton's url with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, telerik, telerik-radribbonbar

I am using Telerik's RibbonBar in ASP.NET. Here is a part of my view:

```
 <!--SOME CODE-->
<telerik:RibbonBarGroup Text="Paragraph" Width="700px">
  <Items>
     <telerik:RibbonBarButton Size="Large" CssClass="barButtons" ImageUrlLarge="\image\bospozvar2.png" Text="Cut" ImageUrl="\image\bospozvar2.png"></telerik:RibbonBarButton>
     <telerik:RibbonBarButton Size="Large" CssClass="barButtons" ImageUrlLarge="\image\servisyok2.png" Text="Cut" ImageUrl="\image\servisyok2.png"></telerik:RibbonBarButton>
     <telerik:RibbonBarButton Size="Large" CssClass="barButtons" ImageUrlLarge="\image\vekaletyok2.png" Text="Cut" ImageUrl="\image\vekaletyok2.png"></telerik:RibbonBarButton>
     <telerik:RibbonBarButton Size="Large" CssClass="barButtons" ImageUrlLarge="\image\ggyok2.png" Text="Cut" ImageUrl="\image\ggyok2.png"></telerik:RibbonBarButton>
     <telerik:RibbonBarButton Size="Large" CssClass="barButtons" ImageUrlLarge="\image\fastyok2.png" Text="Cut" ImageUrl="\image\fastyok2.png"></telerik:RibbonBarButton>
     <telerik:RibbonBarButton Size="Large" CssClass="barButtons" ImageUrlLarge="\image\USyok2.png" Text="Cut" ImageUrl="\image\USyok2.png"></telerik:RibbonBarButton>
  </Items>
</telerik:RibbonBarGroup>
<!--SOME MORE CODE-->
```

And my jquery:

```
$(".barButtons").click(function () {
        var logo = $(this).attr("src");
        alert(logo);
    });
```

I am trying to get the image url of clicked ribbonbarbutton but it returns as undefined. I know I get the clicked ribbonbarbutton but it seems '.attr('src')' is not working for ribbonbarbuttons. I also tried things like '$(this).attr("ImageUrl");' and '$(this).attr("url");' but all returned undefined.

Answer (score 0):

What you will need is to get a reference to the RibonBarButton using this JS method, [findButtonByValue](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/ribbonbar/client-side-programming/overview#getting-an-instance-of-a-particular-ribbonbarbutton). It means that you will need to assign unique value to each of your RibbonBarButton there. Once you have a reference, then you can call `get_imageUrl` to get the image URL.

```
var ribbonbar = $find("RadRibbonBar1");
var button0 = ribbonbar.findButtonByValue("RibbonBarButton0Value");
```